# JS code cannot solve

Tags: javascript

> Write a function that takes a number n and a function f, and returns a function g.
>
> When you call g() it calls f() at most n times.
>
> ex.

```
function log() {
  console.log('called log');
}
var onlyLog = only(3, log);
onlyLog(); -> outputs 'called log' to console
onlyLog(); -> outputs 'called log' to console
onlyLog(); -> outputs 'called log' to console
onlyLog(); -> does nothing
onlyLog(); -> does nothing
```

MY CODE BELOW:

```
toolbox.only = function(n, f) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    var called = false;
    return function() {
      if (!called) {
        f();
        called = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My code is not passing the following test: calling only(3, f) more than 3 times should call f() 3 times.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, for starters, `return`ing within a loop would terminate that loop instantly. So your loop essentially only ever runs one iteration.

Comment: Let's start with the basics. Do you really think you need a `for` loop? Are you repeating anything some number of times immediately? Why do you think your code only works for one call?

Comment: Oo, I thought I wanted to call functionf n times, but I see I misread that.  I see why my loop wouldn't even loop though.  I didn't notice that at all before, thanks for pointing that out.  I am curious if I wanted to output the f function n times, what that code would look like, since that was what I was trying to solve (because I misread the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you was over thinking the problem..

Try this below..

```js
// Write a function that takes a number n and a function f, and returns a function g.
// When you call g() it calls f() at most n times.

// ex.
//  function log() {
//    console.log('called log');
//  }
//  var onlyLog = only(3, log);
//  onlyLog(); -> outputs 'called log' to console
//  onlyLog(); -> outputs 'called log' to console
//  onlyLog(); -> outputs 'called log' to console
//  onlyLog(); -> does nothing
//  onlyLog(); -> does nothing

var only = function(n, f) {
  return function () {
    if (n) {
      n --;
      f();
    }
  }
}

function log() {
  console.log('called log');
}
var onlyLog = only(3, log);
onlyLog();// -> outputs 'called log' to console
onlyLog();// -> outputs 'called log' to console
onlyLog();// -> outputs 'called log' to console
onlyLog();// -> does nothing
onlyLog();// -> does nothing
```